# Soft actor-critic reinforcement learning for 100x100 maze environment

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, ai, actor-critic

I am doing a project which requires a soft actor-critic reinforcement learning agent to learn how to reach a goal in a 100x100 maze environment as the one below:

[image]

- The state space is discrete and only the agent's current position is
  passed as the state. For example, the state is (50, 4) in the image.
- The action-space is also discrete and just includes [left, right, up,
  down, up-left, up-right, down-left, down-right].
- The reward function is just 100 for reaching the goal.
- My implementation and hyper-parameters closely follow the [openai spinningup](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/sac.html?highlight=soft%20actor-critic) implementation, with tweaking for best performance.

I have tried a tonne of different things, like different discount-rates, hyper-paramter choices, network architectures, reward-shaping (distance and manhattan distance) etc, but I just can't manage to get it to learn.

I know that it is a hard problem and that the reward-shaping isn't too good because the problem is quite non-linear. Also only giving the current location as the state-space may be problematic since the agent does not know the location of walls.

Some things to note:

1. I need to use soft actor-critic, since this is just one component in a larger system.
2. I tried passing through the image pixels as data, but this makes it super slow to train, given my somewhat restricted resources.
3. Any solution needs to generalise to continuous action-spaces eventually.

Does anyone have any good ideas for solving a problem like this? Any tips or advice would be so appreciated!

Comment: You would need to pass the whole 100x100 array to hope the agent learns something, with each element in the array somehow signifying what is present there. This might make it slow to learn, but I don't see a workaround.

Comment: Also entities location should be randomize at the beginning of every episode. After many iterations the agent will be close to the goal and by chance it will reach it and thus you will get a positive reward signal.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses! I have played around with randomised starting points before. It is generally useful, but doesn't seem to (on it's own) work for this. I encoded the state-space onto a flattened 100*100 array with simple encodings (empty=0, wall=1, goal=2 etc). I am just wondering if the dimensionality gets lost here. Is it better to keep it 2-Dimensional and use a CNN to to parse the state?

Comment: Not necessary, a flat array is fine, the encodings are also fine. This is not an easy problem to solve for a NN, have you tried the simpler DQN model with experience replay and a target network?

Comment: Yeh it appears that it is a tough problem for a NN. I haven't tried a DQN because it needs to be applicable to continuous action-spaces in other settings and also off-policy - hence the choice of SAC. It might still be worth trying with DQN to get some more insight into the problem. I have a feeling that the policy network might be more of a distraction than a benefit in this scenario... 

Thanks so much btw, I appreciate the help.